# Data storage: "grouping" entities by property value? (like a dictionary/map?)

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using AppEngine datastore, but this might be agnostic, no idea.

Assume a database entity called `Comment`. Each `Comment` belongs to a `User`. Every `Comment` has a `date` property, pretty standard so far.

I want something that will let me: specify a `User` and get back a dictionary-ish (coming from a Python background, pardon. Hash table, map, however it should be called in this context) data structure where:

- keys: every `date` appearing in the `User`'s comment
- values: `Comments` that were made on `date`.

I guess I could just iterate over a range of dates an build a map like this myself, but I seriously doubt I need to "invent" my own solution here.

Is there a way/tool/technique to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datastore supports both references and list properties. This let's you build one-to-many relationships in two ways:

1. Parent (User) has a list property containing keys of Child entities (Comment).
2. Child has a key property pointing to Parent.

Since you need to limit Comments by date, you'd best go with option two. Then you could query Comments which have date=somedate (or date range) and where user=someuserkey.

There is no native grouping functionality in Datastore, so to also "group" by date, you can add a sort on date to the query. Than when you iterate over the result, when the date changes you can use/store it as a grouping key.

**Update**

Designing no-sql databases should be access-oriented (versus datamodel oriented in sql): for often-used operations you should be getting data out as cheaply (= as few operations) as possible.

So, as a rule of thumb you should, in one operation, only get data that is needed at that moment (= shown on that page to user). I'm not sure about your app's design, but I doubt you need all user's full comments (with text and everything) at one time.

Comment: Actually, doing #2 implicitly does #1: it creates a _set property in the parent entity, so it's not really two different approaches, is it? Anyways, so, dumb iteration and watching out for changes in dateit is? I was actually hoping for something MapReduce-esque. Or indexish. Oh, well. But I'll keep looking. I want something nicer.

Comment: No, surely not in Java. I'm not using Python, but quite sure it does not. 1. and 2. make references in different directions: in 1. parent points to children, in 2. a child point to parent.

Comment: Map reduce is just a technique how to process a large chunk of data, by splitting it up (mapping) and doing some operation that produces some result (reducing). It was mainly useable in doing reporting/OLAP and on NoSQL systems that did not have classical queries.

Comment: About "indexish": you gonna need indexes in any case if you query on more than one property - which you are (date, user).

Comment: Ah, right, maybe Java doesn't do that. Python does. Thanks for the additional input, I'm going to get back to this in a day or two, off to a different project at the moment.

Comment: Just checked - Python does not automatically do two way references (= #2 implicitly does #1). Using `ReferenceProperty(Comment)` in User, just adds a `comment_set` property to user entity in database.

Comment: Did you mean "using `ReferenceProperty(Comment)` in `User` adds a `user_set` property to `Comment`"? Because that's what happens. Anyway, define "two-way". It is a fact that referencing A from B creates a reference from A to B. Is that two-way enough?

Comment: Yes you are right, I just checked Python docs in more detail. Using `user = ReferenceProperty(User)` in `Comment`, will create `comment_set` property in `user` entity. By two-way I mean that Python's ReferenceProperty stores references on both end of relationship. So you can do `comment.user` to get a user that wrote the comment, or `user.comment_set.get()` to get to comments of the user. Two-way also means that when a new `Comment` is saved, two write operations will happen: comment put and user update.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by saying you shouldn't apologize for having a Python background. App Engine started supporting only Python. Using the db module, you could have a User entity as the parent of several DailyCommentBatch entities each a parent of a couple Comment entities. IIRC, this will keep all related entities stored together (or close).

If you are using the NDB (I love it) you may have employ a StructuredProperty either at the User or DailyCommentBatch levels.